# Settling Debts -- Minimize all debts among people

Tags: algorithm, np

I'm encountering a problem about Settling Debt that I can't fix. The problem is similar to Leetcode 465(Optimal Account Balancing).

The input format is a list of transaction (like [[1, 3, 2], [1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 2]] and that means person 3 owes person 1 2$, person 4 owes person 1 3$ and person 4 owes person 2 2$), and you need to return the minimized transactions that suffices minimum number of transaction, just as the input format ([[1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 2]]).

Since the Solutions on Leetcode only return the minimum number of transactions, which makes the problem much easier to solve.

Does anyone know the algorithm to solve this?

Here is the link to the Leetcode 465
https://leetcode.com/problems/optimal-account-balancing/description/

Comment: The problem looks like a DAG with weights. And you need to find an MST of it.

Comment: We might add edges to the graph. like[ [1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 5] ]turn to[ [1, 3, 5] ]. So I think it's different with MST.